# Convert AJAX implementation into jQuery AJAX implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have an implementation of AJAX, How to exactly replicate this with jQuery AJAX

```
var request;
function sendInfo()
{
    var id = document.form.bid.value;
    var url="retrieve.jsp?bid="+id;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        request=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    try
    {
        request.onreadystatechange=getInfo;
        request.open("GET",url,true);
        request.send();
    } catch (e)
    {
         alert("Unable to connect to server");
    }
}
```

I need to send a data bid onkeyup, display some data into the 'dispArea'

```
function getInfo()  
{  
    if(request.readyState==4)  
    {  
        var val = request.responseText;  
        document.getElementById('dispArea').innerHTML=val;  
    }  
}
```

Implement the same using jQuery AJAX

What I have tried ::

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#bookid').keyup(function(){
         $.ajax({
             url : 'retrieve.jsp',
             data : {
                  bid : $('bookid').val()
             },
             success : function(responseText){
                 $('#dispArea').text(responseText);
             }
         });
     });
});
```

bid is not available in the retrieve jsp file.

Comment: What have you tried in this replication process?

Comment: I've updated the question, please go through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt use # symbol in referring to the id "#bookid".
and to receive the text as html.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bookid').keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'retrieve.jsp',
            type : 'POST',
            async : 'false',
            data : {
                bid : $('#bookid').val()
            },
            success : function(responseText){
                $('#dispArea').html(responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```